# Question on fluid dynamics and flow thorough horizontal pipe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

In a streamlined flow, which is laminar, non viscous and steady, of a liquid through a horizontal pipe, if the pressure and velocity at a point upstream are $p$ and $v$ respectively and those at a point in downstream are $p\prime$ and $2v$ respectively then, $p$=$X$$p\prime$.
Then the value of $X$ is?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Comment: In inviscid flow through a horizontal pipe of constant cross section, the pressure and velocity are constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not precise it, I guess the flow is laminar, non-viscous and steady. Then, you can apply Bernoulli energy conservation law between two points of the same streamline :

$P_{1} + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_{1}^{2} + \rho g h_{1}=P_{2} + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_{2}^{2} + \rho g h_{2}$

The fluid is laminar and non-viscous thus there is such a streamline between (1) and (2), and the height is constant so you get in the end (assuming (2) is downstream) :

$P_{1}-P_{2}=\frac{3}{2} \rho v^{2}$

As you can see there is no general X factor between the two pressures, it depends on the volumic mass and the entry speed of the flow.

EDIT (top up) : Actually the conservation of the volumic energy is independent of the streamline in the case of an irrotational flow, which is here guaranteed by the fact that the flow is inviscid (cf. Kelvin's Theorem).

Comment: Np. Please edit your question with all the hypothesis of the problem, for someone may have the same problem in the future

Comment: There technically is a X factor between the two, it just isn't pretty (it still depends on p').  You can divide it out to get $p = p'(1 + \frac{\frac{3}{2} \rho v^2}{p'})$